# Doctrine ORM -> how to set result to an array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

From my query i receive some values. I try to use if(in_array( but doesnt work. Whats the best solutions? Below you see my solution:

```
$beheerdersArray = array();
                    foreach($club->getUsers() AS $result){
                        $beheerdersArray[] = $result->getId();
                    }
                    echo 'User ID: '.$user->getId();

                    if(!in_array($user->getId(),$beheerdersArray)){
                        echo 'Beheerder niet gevonden';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Beheerder gevonden';
                    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Doesn't work how? have you tried echoing the values of $user->getId() and $beheerdersArray?

Comment: The question is: how to make from this result: $club = $this->em->getRepository('Club')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id)); an array

The $beheerdersArray works, but there must be an easier way of convering the result from the query to an array

Comment: Are you trying to see whether the current `$user` is a member of `$club`?

Comment: Yeah. What i do now, is getting all users that can edit the club. Then i convert them to an array with a foreach. There must be a way to make an array of the repository way easyier

Comment: You shouldn't be using an array to do this at all. Instead, this logic should be encapsulated within the Club entity and invoked like `$club->hasUser($user)`. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `$club->getUsers()` is probably returning a Doctrine ArrayCollection which is not a true array. If you called `$club->getUsers()->toArray()`, you would get the internal array with which you can use in_array().

You could also try the `contains()` method in [Array Collection](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php) if the user object you already have was fetched from Doctrine. Something like `$this->em->getRepository('Club')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id))->contains($user);`

Comment: Also could do `$this->em->getRepository('Club')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id))->toArray();`

Comment: If i add the toArray, i still get a hugh list when i print_r the array... Can you explain me why that is?

Comment: `toArray()` returns an array with `User` objects. Due to the way Doctrine works, there's a lot more than just the object properties to `print_r` when you're working with an object that it hydrated from a database. I've added another thing to try to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of whether a user belongs to a club is something that the Club entity should take ownership of:

```
// Controller
if ($club->hasUser($user)) {
    echo "User is a member";
}


// Club Entity
public function hasUser(User $user)
{
    foreach ($this->getUsers() as $member) {
        if ($member->getId() === $user->getId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Foreach`ing over each user and comparing the id is not very efficient at all, but without knowing much more about your application, it's hard to suggest the *best* way to perform this comparison. Regardless, you've now got some encapsulated, reusable domain logic rather than a procedural script.